# SAML2 email address as NameId is discourage to use

Tags: authentication, authorization, saml-2.0

I'm starting to work on implementing SAML2 Authentication with a Federation. One of the requirements are the federation is required to send us back persistent value for the NameId this is because it serves as one of the keys I identify when a user is logging in using SAML2 SSO to a web app.

I was about to use the `<NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>`, however one of the support of the federation that we will be consuming to connect to organization discourage me to use the email address nameid. I haven't got the chance to ask why? Is there a reason why an email address is not the best choice to use for the NameIdFormat for SAML2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AD, email can be duplicated across two accounts. There is no constraint for uniqueness.

It depends on the use case. If it's corporate, it will rarely change. If it's public, there's much more churn.

UPN can be a better choice.